# Different Objects in ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, java-io, objectoutputstream

When sending self made Objects over an ObjectOutputStream, do the server and client class of that Object have to be the same?

For example, when some Action can only be performed on a server because it needs several other classes only available on the server, can the class on the client be different from the one on the server?

Server class:

```
public class SomeAction implements Action, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //Just some serialVersionUID
    private String name;

    public SomeAction(String name) {
        //This property must be sent to the server
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public void performAction() {
        System.out.println("New client connected");
        Server.getConnections().add(1); //Increases the number of connections on the server. Of course, this is only available on the server.

        //Do something with the client
        . . .

    }

}
```

Client class:

```
public class SomeAction implements Action, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //Just some serialVersionUID
    private String name;

    public SomeAction(String name) {
        //This property must be sent to the server
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    public void performAction() {
        System.out.println("New client connected");
        //The getConnections().add(1) wont work on the client.

        //Do something with the client
        . . .

    }

}
```

Now can the client send its class to the server, and will the server then call the `performAction()` method from its own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes can be different, but not too much different. There are several rules concerning the 'compatibility' between those classes.

See

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html

For example one can add new methods to the class, and keep the serialVersionUID field to the same value, and don't use the new methods - this does not disturb, of course.

*Update:*

Better link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20051125013312/http://www.macchiato.com/columns/Durable4.html

Comment: So, as long as they have at least all standard methods (for example, all inherited from Action) and all standard fields, there can be difference inside those methods or additional methods/fields in the class, am I right?

Comment: a) What is inside the methods doesn't matter for all this stuff of compatibility - if your Java program runs on the server, the JVM will use the class file which is on the server, and does not care or check if the contents of the method is different from that one the client or whereever.

Comment: b) If you e.g. delete a method (which is used somewhere), this is of course a problem. Adding new methods shouldn't be bad, as far as I remember. Renaming is a bad idea, it's like deleting. 

I finally found a good link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20051125013312/http://www.macchiato.com/columns/Durable4.html

Comment: They write e.g.:

Here are some of the things you can't do without some work:

change the superclass
remove a field
change the name of a field
change a field to static (from non-static)
change a field to transient (from non-transient)
change the type of a primitive field to anything else (e.g. byte to short)
change the type of a non-primitive field to primitive (e.g. Character to char)